# what is FastCGI? whether it is an alternative to CGI?

Tags: cgi, fastcgi

Recently i heard about 'FastCGI' word,as i have used CGI.I have no idea whether this fastCGi really works fast.i.e,does it really provides best efficiency and performance? or not? as there are many alternative options in the market for CGI.so,which is the best technique CGI,FastCGI or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

FastCGI is a language independent extension of CGI and has all the features of CGI plus additional benefits when it comes to scaling your applications with distributed computing and using multiple nodes to host your application.

You can go through some links like [the official website](https://fastcgi-archives.github.io/) and even though [this link](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgi/) is old, its a good read